# How to read SIM SENT SMS Messages from android programmatically?

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to load all SIM SENT SMS Messages but i don't know what's the content provider URI except 
**"content://sms/icc" and "content://sms/sim",** and these uris load only recieved messages.

How can I load SIM Sent Messages ??

Answer (score 0):

You can access the **sent messages** in android by using this URI.

---

> Uri sentURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

---